# Weblogic 10.3 with axis

Tags: weblogic-10.x

I am migrating from weblogic 8.1 to 10.3 with JRockit1.6. When accesing the webservice using jaxrpc.Call.Invoke() method, it throws NullPointerException.

I had a workaround fix of using the Xerces.jar to be preloaded in the weblogic prior weblogic.jar.

But i dont want to use the xerces.jar as this is going to be a additional jar. Please let me know if you guys had come across these kind of situations to overcome this.

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.io.FilterInputStream.available(FilterInputStream.java:142)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:325)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager$RewindableInputStream.read(XMLEntityManager.java:2939)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:292)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1742)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipSpaces(XMLEntityScanner.java:1492)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:872)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:647)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:508)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:109)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:523)
 at weblogic.xml.jaxp.WebLogicXMLReader.parse(WebLogicXMLReader.java:134)
 at weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLReader.parse(RegistryXMLReader.java:172)
 at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:396)
 at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
 at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
 at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
 at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:796)
 at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:144)
 at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:33)
 at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
 at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:85)
 at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
 at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
 at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
 at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
 at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
 at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you want to use the xerces.jar? Axis requires it.
Weblogic 8 had different sets of jars included (that caused conflict) but obviously allowed your app to work.